# Split a Tensorflow Dataset into Train, Validation, Test sets, does this code cause data leakage?

Tags: python, tensorflow, split, dataset, train-test-split

I imported a folder that contains 3 folders of images insidethe , each belonging to one class, suppose cats and dogs. I created TensorFlow dataset by (**shuffle=True**) :

```
ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory('/content/data',
                                                    labels='inferred',
                                                    label_mode='int',
                                                    batch_size=32,
                                                    image_size=(256, 256),
                                                    shuffle=True)
```

**Suppose len(ds) = 10**

is it a correct way of splitting ds to train, Val, and test datasets? I found it on some websites and youtube videos including towardsdatascience.com:

```
train_ds = ds.take(8)    
val_ds = ds.skip(8).take(1)
test_ds = ds.skip(8).skip(1)
```

**my question is:** when the **shuffle=True** in image_dataset_from_directory function, each time I call ds.take(n) (n could be any integer less than 10), **it returns different outputs**, so I conclude that: **it is highly probable that some** **data from train_ds exists in val_ds and test_ds. I mean there is data leakage**...
Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation below
[Doc](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/)

It suffle only shuffle your data if true , other rake it inaccending order, and tosplit data you can use  your code , many people do this and this does not show data leakage